# Saudi Arabia motivations for OPEC production cut

Tags: oil

I'm wondering whether one of Saudi Arabia's principle motivations for supporting OPEC production cuts is so that the price of crude oil will increase and so Saudi Aramco, Saudi's state-owned oil company, will be valued higher prior to its upcoming IPO?

I would appreciate any help understanding whether this is the case.

Comment: It's definitely a plausible motivation.

Answer (score 1):

You could think this in terms of an oligopoly. As an imperfect market, firms get more profits than possible in a competitive market because decisions around levels of production influence prices. All members of the OPEC have an incentive to reduce production as a whole (to raise prices), and an incentive to increase production individually (to earn more profits at those higher prices).

You can also consider political issues like production outside the cartel: they don't hold a monopoly and the higher the OPEC raises prices, firms with costlier ways of extracting oil (like fracking in the US) can turn a profit and compete with them, which naturally reduces profits (and value).

While the IPO may be a possible explanation, you can think of it in terms of oligopolies and still get a reasonable answer.